# Trying to modify a template

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

My client got an template for his store and I need to modify the page title. The problem is that there are inline styles and I'm not finding a way to remove them:

```
<div class="page-title">
    <p>
      <span style="font-size: small;">
         <strong>
           <span style="font-family: verdana, geneva; color: #543a1d;">DESTAQUES</span>  
         </strong>
      </span>
   </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

please refer below link to change page title of any page you need to goto xml or block title

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/change-any-page-title-in-magento/

Answer (score -1):

You can find the file where this code is using Templates hints

http://www.westwideweb.com/wp/2009/08/04/magento-how-to-turn-on-template-path-hints-and-inline-translation/